# REAL sort an array without loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, echo, asort

I'm looking for sort an array WITHOUT foreach loop (direct command)...

for example :

```
<?php

$sortme = array( 10, 8, 17, 6, 22, 4, 3, 87, 1);

asort($sortme);

echo $sortme[0]; //Why this is not the lowest value (which is 1 on this case) ?!

//Is there any direct command sort array WITHOUT foreach loop ?

// iow...
// I need this :
// $sortme = array( 10, 8, 17, 6, 22, 4, 3, 87, 1);
// (here is the magic command) to become this :
// $sortme = array( 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 17, 22, 87);
?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Read the manual. `asort()` preserves keys. You probably want `sort()`.

Comment: Because you used `asort()` instead of `sort()`.  If you `print_r($sortme)` your array you'll find it sorted but the keys out of order. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: Hehe I can't believe that I was so easy! thanks John ! :D

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you just need sort()

```
<?php
    $sortme = array( 10, 8, 17, 6, 22, 4, 3, 87, 1);
    sort($sortme);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($sortme);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo 'First: '.$sortme[0];
?>
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 17
    [7] => 22
    [8] => 87
)
First: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("3" => "lemon", "4" => "orange", "2" => "banana", "1" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

Should give you this output:

```
1 = apple
2 = banana
3 = lemon
4 = orange
```

Comment: Thanks man! But sort was the magic command (instead of asort) :) ...and I was looking for the cleanest method (without loop)... but thanks !